# Streaming Video Inside a Mesh in Blender

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been searching for a solution for streaming a video inside a mesh in Blender, but I couldn't find a proper resource.

Is it possible to do it? For example, is there a way to play a Twitch or YouTube video in real time?

I tried a method like this but it didn't work. I tried to replace the texture in the path of the texture in the material of the mesh in realtime. But the texture didn't refresh unless I closed Blender.

Does anyone have a solution to this?